# Docusign custom button

Tags: docusignapi

I created a custom "Send with DocuSign" button in SFDC on a custom object. The button seems to be working properly, but will not pull any documents from the Notes and Attachments. I have looked thru the documentation and tried this way:

```
<apex:commandbutton value="Send with DocuSign"  id="DocuSign" onClick="DocuSign_CreateEnvelope(); return false;"/>
```

and this:

```
<apex:commandbutton value="Send with DocuSign"  id="DocuSign" onClick="window.location.href = '/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope?DSEID=0&SourceID={!CRDNTLS__Credentials_Answers__c.Id};' return false;"/>
```

neither of which seem to work.

Comment: Please remove the generic "docusign" tag and add tag DocuSignAPI - that's what's used for DocuSign development / api questions...

Answer (score 0):

Can you try removing dsfs__ from '/apex/dsfs__DocuSign_CreateEnvelope". Let me know if it helps. 
For the second one try "window.location.href = '/apex/DocuSign_CreateEnvelope....